# How to use loadTestsFromTestCase to load SubClass through BaseClass?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

As below code, it cannot discover subclass.

But I want to execute the tests(test_sub_1,test_sub_2) in testcase_subA.

Are there any method to load subclass testcase through baseclass?
(without unittest.main())

```
import unittest
    
class testcase_A(unittest.TestCase):
    text= "Base class"

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass A")

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp A")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown A")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass A")


class testcase_subA(testcase_A):
    def test_sub_1(self):
        print(self.text)
        print("test sub A 1")

    def test_sub_2(self):
        print("test sub A 2")

class testcase_B(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass B")

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp B")

    def test_b(self):
        print("test B")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown B")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass B")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suiteA = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testcase_A)
    suiteB = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testcase_B)
    suite = unittest.TestSuite([suiteA, suiteB])
    print(suite)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
```

Output:

> setUpClass B
>
> setUp B
>
> test B
>
> tearDown B
>
> tearDownClass B

Answer (score 1):

So your subclassA will only run if you specify it. If you tell it to just run the parent class it would only run the parent. If you had tests in that parent class of A you would see an output but you do not. So when I edit your runner to include testcase_subA then I get the output I think you want. If you run the test with test modules such as pytest or nose2 it shows the same thing as well

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        suiteA = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testcase_subA)
        suiteB = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testcase_B)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite([suiteA, suiteB])
        print(suite)
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
        runner.run(suite)
```

I get the output of

```
setUpClass A
setUp A
Base class
test sub A 1
tearDown A
.setUp A
test sub A 2
tearDown A
.tearDownClass A
setUpClass B
setUp B
test B
tearDown B
.tearDownClass B
```